# How to create odbc dsn by service account (non-interactive windows account)

Tags: odbc, sql-server-2017

How to create odbc dsn by service account (non-interactive windows account).

I have tried with SQL ACCOUNT & WINDOWS USER ACCOUNT both are working without any issues and able to talk with SQLDB.  But I am unable to open odbc32.exe to create DSN by Windows Service Account which is non-interactive.